# Request scoped beans only in an Ajax-rich JSF application

Tags: jsf, primefaces, scope, request, javabeans

Is it feasible and is it a good idea to use only request scoped beans in the entire JSF2.2 application? Specifically, in an Ajax-rich application that contains multiple PrimeFaces components such as datatables with lazy loading? The application does not have to be stateless, as it is ok to save view state on the client side. And I am aware that by using OmniFaces also ViewScoped beans could be saved on the client side. In fact, I have tried it out, and it works perfectly fine. Still, it is expected that I should be able to use request scoped beans only.

The application will run on multiple servers, and it would be preferred to avoid using HTTP-Session database. There also might be other limitations I am not aware of. Hence the wish not to save state on the server side.

I am somewhat experienced with JSF, but I have never needed to deal with such requirements. To be honest, I barely ever used request-scoped beans, as I did not find them particularly useful. And I have tried to research the subject online, but I seem not to find anything at all that would be related with the matter. So any advice, hints, links, or anything else would be immensely useful.